# A question on $ L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Question- Let {$f_k$} be a sequence in $ L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty||f_k||_1<\infty$. Prove that the series  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f_k$ converges in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\lambda(dx)$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int_\mathbb{R}f_k(x)\lambda(dx)$. Do not assume completeness of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Can you please give me an easier solution with minimal measure theory usage. I haven't done a course in measure theory, but i studied basics of it on my own. Its a functional analysis question in my assignment. I have no where to go. Its due today. Please help. it will be many thanks. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem?

Comment: If $f(x,y)$ is integrable, it allows order of integration to be changed. i Understand the statement, not proof of it though. If u can do this by using Fubini, its fine.

Comment: One of the first things, you shold notice is that $ |\int f_k|\leq \int |f_k|$ . On the right hand side, adding the terms, you find a monotone sequence. Then you should check the monotone convergence Theorem and Fatou's lemma

Comment: Summation is really the same as integration. Define $F(x,y) = f_k(x)$ where $k-1 < y \le k$.  Then
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\; \lambda(dx) = \int_{-\infty} \int_0^\infty F(x,y)\; \lambda(dy) \lambda(dx)$ and 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty ...$ is the same integral in the other order.

Comment: In this $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty ...$ if i break $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ as $\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^\infty$, then what do i do with summation on the outside. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\ = F(x,y)$ Right? But now integrations are between $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ & $f_k(x)$

Comment: got it. now i use fubini